# Grails 3: Configure SSO to custom OAuth2 server

Tags: spring, grails, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, grails-3.1

I want to configure SSO authorization to my custom OAuth2 server, written on Grails with grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider.

I successfully configured demo REST API server on Spring Boot 1.4.0 and Spring Cloud Security for using this authorization server.

But if I try to do this with my Grails API, I don't get the expected result.

I get 302 http status, whenever I do.

I'v tried to do the same config as on Spring Boot proj, but nothing happens.

What can i try? Thank you in advance.

**UPD:**

Auth server returns right data (access_token, etc.).

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.8.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.10"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "grailswithsso"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"

    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:1.1.2.RELEASE"

    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

**Application.groovy**

```
import grails.boot.GrailsApp
import grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso

@EnableOAuth2Sso
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
oauth2:
  client:
    clientId: xxx
    clientSecret: xxx
    accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8181/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8181/oauth/authorize
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  resource:
    userInfoUri: http://localhost:8181/user
    preferTokenInfo: false
```

Comment: SSO and OAuth are really two different things. Can you edit your question to include some code to illustrate what you are trying to do and how?

Comment: @helgew ok, i added config parts of my proj